# Create an approval email workflow that inserts list item

Tags: designer-workflow, email

I'm trying to create a workflow that will send out emails to users after someone creates an item in a document library or list.

The user will receive the email in outlook and will use the voting buttons to accept or reject the event invitation.

If the user accepts the invitation it should insert an item into a list that shows the persons name.

My question is how do I go about creating a new list item based on the persons response in his/her email?

I'm learning really quickly so I just need something to get me started

Comment: A link to another site would work nicely but I never could find something that satisfied what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside SharePoint Designer, when in the workflow editor screen, you are able to change the Workflow Completion Conditions, and add additional logic or conditions there. So, you can add your insert item action after your success condition. This may be under the task behavior actions in SPD.

See the link below for office.microsoft.com reference:
[link here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx#_Toc264526223)

> Change the completion conditions for the task process
>   The first option available is to change the completion conditions for the task process. When you open the completion conditions for the Approval workflow, you see all of the conditions that must be met for the workflow to be considered complete. For example, if the number of approved tasks equals the completed task count, then the approved variable is set to Yes. You can add more logic here so that a different set of conditions are required for the workflow to be complete or you can leave the existing conditions in place.>

Comment: Yes I realize that I can edit the approval process.  But how can I configure it to use the voting options in outlook where if the user accepts the invite in outlook, then insert a new list item.  Most of the approval process has to do with doing something on the SharePoint site, not Outlook.

Comment: Also quick question is it possible to create a new list using a workflow in SharePoint Designer?  Yes or no will work I'm not looking for someone to do it for me

Comment: The Outlook Task syncs with the SharePoint Approval Task. The Accept/Reject buttons in outlook, for the outlook task, will cause outcomes for the SharePoint Task item.
The above directions will provide to you the instructions to complete your request. 
- Create a new approval workflow. Click into the Approval Task. View the outcome conditions. Inside the completion conditions, for the approved section, add an additional action that inserts an new item into your "event" list.

No, you cannot create a new list as an action in a sharepoint workflow. You can create a new list item, though.